# Wordpress Main Menu - Hide 'Home' link on homepage only

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to hide the "Home" link that's generated from Wordpress main menu on the homepage, and show it on the rest of the site.

I tried creating my own menu with no "Home" link and adding the "Home" link manually on the header.php file but it goes to the end of the menu and does not look like a pretty solution.

Any ideas?  Using latest Wordpress 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to hide it to the users, i suggest using the following `CSS`:

```
body.home a[title="Home"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Explanation: Wordpress generates several classes for the body tag. The `home` class is used to hide all links with the title `Home` on the homepage.

Working Example (code taken from the default theme): http://jsfiddle.net/yJVyK/1/

Note: The [attribute selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html) does not work in IE6

Comment: Thanks Martin, that worked.  Don't care much for IE6 for this site, thankfully ...

Answer (score 0):

There is an another solution with PHP which more correct way in my opinion.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'amc_filter_menu', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Filters to remove Home Link on Front Page
 */
function amc_filter_menu( $objects, $args ) {

    // Return Default Value if the Menu isn't Main Menu
  // Replace "Navigation_location" with your target location
    if ( 'Navigation_location' !== $args->theme_location ) {
        return $objects;
    }

    // Detect the Menu which equeal site URL
    foreach ( $objects as $key => $object ) :

        if ( get_site_url( null, '/' ) === $object->url && is_front_page() || get_site_url() === $object->url && is_front_page() ) :
            unset( $objects[ $key ] );
        endif;

    endforeach;

    // Return the menu objects
    return $objects;

}
```

[Source](https://alidemirci.com/remove-menu-item-from-home-page-in-wordpress/)