# How to remove the home from the wordpress menu?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, parallax

I am using wordpress 3.9.1, and an appdev theme. how can i remove the home tab from the menu. i have found some css options it is working. Is there any right method of doing this? means how can we handle this from the php side?

```
body.home a[title="Home"] {
    display: none;
}
```

i am using appdev parallax theme. home tab is showing in the child pages also.[Css Trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263639/wordpress-main-menu-hide-home-link-on-homepage-only) i have not added home page to the menu. theme it self is taking home as default..

Comment: Why not remove it in the menu setup?

Comment: this is not correct way..you can remove it from dashboard->appearance->menu and set pages from there..

Comment: You can handle your navigation menus from **wp-admin -> Apperence -> Menus**. Are not you ..?

Comment: Sorry i have not added the home page to the menu. theme it self is taking home as default.

Comment: remove from menu builder wp-admin/nav-menus.php

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/24027)?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal which line i want to remove from this page?

Comment: @brasofilo tried nothing happened

Comment: at right side you have option to remove menu

Comment: I have added another menu but the home is coming over there

Answer (score 0):

When you set the home page under setting -> reading -> set static page as home page, Wordpress creates a custom link in your menu settings under appearance named Home, I'm not sure if this is suppose to happen or if it's a bug but you can just go to your menu settings and remove the custom link tab from the builder and save your menu.

Also check that the menu location is set, otherwise a list of your top pages will be displayed in the front end as your menu.

Hope this helps.